# One div per scroll in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an idea but I do not know where to start. I want to make my site which is comprised of four rows of div to be scrollable but one division per scroll (means it must adjust to the screen size 100% in height and width) or just by clicking the arrow down/up button. Where should I start in implementing this? Is this possible? Please help make my dreams come true. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give this jQuery plugin a shot: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

It has both scroll and click events and a pretty active/up-to-date GitHub repo: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js

Answer (score 1):

I've made a simple example, however fullPage.js worth checking too (+1 [rags02](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1880758/rags02)).

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hBcrb